# Why are values coming in as <Null> when importing table from Excel?

Tags: arcgis-pro, csv, null

[image]

I'm importing a CSV file into ArcGIS Pro, I've used geoprocessing tool XY Table to Point but values have come in null. Column type is double in ArcGIS Pro. Highlighted is the column which imports null from Excel.

[image]

Comment: Possibly the forbidden math expression in the field name ("`-`")

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the formatting of the excel table might have something to do with it? Try changing the data type of that column within excel to a numeric type and the bring them back in. It would also be worth inspecting the data type in Arc-Pro by going to the field management. This can be done by opening the table and clicking add field, which will open a secondary table. If the data type is something like "text", then you have likely discovered that the formatting in excel is the issue at hand.

---

As stated in comments:

> That worked! I changed the file type to .xlsx and then ran table to
> excel.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Using the =ISNUMBER function in excel it returned all the entries in that field were numbers. I also checked the field type in ArcPro, the data type is Double and under the Number Format heading it is Numeric.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do the columns for long and lat import as double or float?

Comment: Both Lat and Long import as double.

Comment: Might try copying and pasting that column into a new column by doing a "Paste Values" in excel and then "Table to Excel" back into Pro. Could fix the issue... Have you tried doing the import more than once? Sometimes there is just an error in the import process.

Comment: That worked! I changed the file type to .xlsx and then ran table to excel.

Comment: Excellent. If you select the above answer others will be able to view it for future reference.